# How to handle events on markup inserted through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="section">
    <input type="text" id="myInput">
</div>
```

On click of a button, I'm cloning and inserting a copy of this markup with unique IDs using this script:

```
var newSection = $("#section").clone();
$(newSection).attr('id', "section" + ($("div[id^=section").length + 1));
$(newSection).find("input").attr('id', "myInput" + ($("input[id^=myInput").length + 1));
$("div[id^=section").last().after(newSection);
```

My resulting markup:

```
<div id="section">
    <input type="text" id="myInput">
</div>
<div id="section2">
    <input type="text" id="myInput2">
</div>
```

My question: is it possible to manipulate this new markup with jQuery? I assume since it has loaded dynamically after a click it's not part of the initial DOM and jQuery doesn't recognize it? I'm having trouble getting a click event to register on `#myInput2`. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `$(newSection).find("input").on('click', function() { alert('hi') })` seems a likely candidate ;)

Comment: jquery can see existing DOM nodes just fine.  If you register an event before the element has been added to the DOM via `.click` then it won't auto-register after - events only wire to elements that exist at the time.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: *I'm having trouble getting a click event to register on #myInput2* - how are you attempting "to register click event" ?

Comment: what are you doing with the inputs? if you're passing them to php for example you are better off naming them 'myinput[]' and get them as an array in php

Comment: Use event delegation on the parent container of your inputs

Comment: Any luck with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap them in a container, you can delegate that container keep track of the buttons. For example, if you have:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="section">
        <input type="text" id="myInput">
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
        <input type="text" id="myInput2">
    </div>
</div>
```

you can delegate the task to the container like this:

```
$("#container").on("click","input",function(){
    var newSection = $("#section").clone();
    $(newSection).attr('id', "section" + ($("div[id^=section").length + 1));
    $(newSection).find("input").attr('id', "myInput" + 
    ($("input[id^=myInput").length + 1));
    $("div[id^=section").last().after(newSection);
}
```

This way you can manipulate them if not defined while binding

**EDIT**: Updated from `.delegate()` to `.on()`

Comment: Don't use `delegate` as it is marked as deprecated in v3, use `.on()` instead

Comment: Didn't notice, thanks for the advice @empiric! I'll update it using `.on( )`

Answer (score 0):

Add classes to your markup:

```
<div id="section" class="section">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" class="section-input">
</div>
```

Simplify your code

```
var $newSection = $('#section').clone();
var $sections = $('.section');
var index = $sections.length +1;
$newSection.attr('id', 'section' + index);
$newSection.find('input').attr('id', 'myInput' + index);

$sections.last().after($newSection);
```

Make sure click handlers are added to existing and new elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.section-input', function(){
    ... your code
})
```